# I'm having trouble making a navbar with a logo in the center, and two links on either side with equal spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I want to create a navbar with a logo in the center, and two navbar items (links) on either side, width equal spacing. I also need the logo to be lined up center with the navbar items.

Here's the code i have thus far. I'm using bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">Navbaritem1 </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> Navbaritem2 </a> </li>
</ul>


<div class="logo">
<img src="Img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Navbaritem3 </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Navbaritem4 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav li {
display: inline;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
}

.logo {
width: 100px;
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
}

.logo img {

float: none;
padding-top:10%;
}

ul {
display: inline;
text-align:center;
width:30%;
}
```

Comment: Google "center logo in navigation bar", Bootstrap has nothing to suite this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try centering a div inside the container?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="center">
  Centered content here
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.center {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div) might've helped you with a quick search.